# Invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'

Tags: c++

When I write `for(auto &i: s)`, the code works, and when I write `for(int &i: s)`, the code fails:

```
[Error] invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'.
```

Can someone please explain me the above problem?

```
int main(){
    int x;
    unordered_set<int> s;
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        cin >> x;
        s.insert(x);
    }
    for(int &i: s)
        cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `unordered_set` has *immutable* keys and, because of that, both the `iterator` and `const_iterator` give you `const` references (there's little point giving a mutable reference when the underlying thing is immutable). The use of `auto` picks this up because of type deduction rules.

The use of `int` does not allow type deduction to apply `const` to it (because type deduction is something that's done for `auto` variables). Hence you need to *explicitly* do that because, as you've seen, it's invalid to treat a `const` reference as a non-`const` one.

In any case, I would be using `const` regardless. It's usually better to be explicit in your intent - if you're not going to *change* a variable, make it `const` so that's obvious. That may also allow the compiler to make certain optimisations it may not otherwise do.

---

As an aside, I've just seen a nice talk from Herb Sutter (search for "Quantifying Accidental Complexity"). This is a proposal to use specifiers like `in`, `out`, `inout` (basically "*what* you want") on your function parameters rather than having to remember if it should be `const`, a value or reference, whether you should forward or move it within a function, and all sorts of other things ("*how* you want to do it").

This is another classic example of coding up intent and will, if it goes ahead, make the language a lot better in my opinion. It both removes the need to know *how* to do what you want, and allows the compiler to do extra checks to make sure you're following the rules (for example, ensuring every code path changes an `out` variable, or ensuring you don't use an `out` variable before assigning to it).

I'd suggest having a look if you're interested in that sort of stuff.